# SHA256 doesn't match

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, sha

The SHA256 associated with my project doesn't match the SHA256 expected by the project.

This problem is a little out my league and I'm not sure how to solve it. Here's my error code:

> Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.hopefullyfinalgeoguessr, may result in stale flags.
>
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.hopefullyfinalgeoguessr, sha256=[a3c1267456d......], atk=false, ver=230714044.true (go/gsrlt)

All I know is that the SHA256 in my keystores doesn't match this one. I'm trying to use the google street view API if that matters.

Comment: Every time you change the app the hash will change and you have to add or update the new hash to the allowed hashes saved at Google.